# How to render FlatList with two array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, logic, react-native-flatlist

I want to render a `FlatList`  with two arrays that are `name` and `photo`. I hope my `FlatList` each of item include name and photo.

But i don't know how to merge them into my `FlatList` data.

console.log my `movieActorCn` array like this:

```
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

movieActorPhoto array like this:

```
["https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w290/i/o/productio…names/June2017/DL56QvvLdISH9D3U1dOR-6144x4096.jpg", "/build/images/noavatar.jpg", "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/h290/i/o/production/names/April2018/dPWzXuXupOAHs2ZW2jdk-408x590.jpg", "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w290/i/o/production/names/April2018/123akbim6D7wsxqnoJJ0-400x266.jpg", "https://movies.yahoo.com.tw/x/r/w290/i/o/productio…names/June2017/DL56QvvLdISH9D3U1dOR-6144x4096.jpg"]
```

I try to merge them by using `Array.prototype.push.apply(movieActorCn, movieActorPhoto);`   I `cosole.log(movieActorCn);` and find the array just cahnge from 5 to 10.  It can't be used if i want to render each item include one name and one photo.

I hope my `renderActor` function can render name and photo. Like render with `<Image />` and `<Text />` How to do it ?

Any help would be apprecriated.  Thanks in advance.

render() {
    const { 
      movieActorCn, movieActorPhoto
    } = this.state.movies;

```
//It just caange from 5 to 10
Array.prototype.push.apply(movieActorCn, movieActorPhoto);
console.log(movieActorCn);

return (
        <FlatList
          data={movieActorPhoto}
          renderItem={this.renderActor}
          horizontal={true}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}  
        />

);
```

}

```
renderActor({ item }) {
    console.log('renderActor');
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <View
        style={{     
          alignSelf: 'stretch',
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          borderRadius: 5,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: '#fff',
          marginLeft: 10,
          marginRight: 10 
        }}
      >
      <Image 
        source={{uri: item }} 
        style={{height: 120, width: equalWidth, resizeMode: 'stretch', flex: 1}}
      />
      </View>
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<FlatList
  data={movieActorPhoto}
  extraData={movieActorCn /* so that list is re-rendered when `movieActorCn` changes */}
  keyExtractor={item => item}
  renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
    <View>
      <Image source={{ uri: item }} />
      <Text>{movieActorCn[index]}</Text>
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

It might be better to change your data structure to

```
[ { name: 'A', photo: 'https://...' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just push your arrays in one array:

```
   let a=[];
   let b=[];
   let c=[];

   c.push(...a);
   c.push(...b);
```